# Input characters from phonetic symbols via keyboard

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I'm using Linux (*Mint Mate*), is it possible to input following characters directly via keyboard, which are phonetic symbols:

> ə, ɔ, ŋ, ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets try...

(1) decision: map ə, ɔ, ŋ,  to (ALTGR+ e c n )

(2) using xmodmap command get the current definition of those chars (e,c,n):

```
xmodmap -pke | grep '= [ecn] ' > myfon.xmap
```

myfon.xmap has 3 lines like:

```
keycode  26 = e E e E EuroSign cent e E e E
keycode  54 = c C c C cent copyright cent copyright c C
keycode  57 = n N n N n N n N n N
```

(3) ALTGR is the 5th column; replace it by the unicode of 'ə, ɔ, ŋ,' ( [ipa-unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_Extensions) )

```
keycode  26 = e E e E U0259 cent e E e E
keycode  54 = c C c C U0254 copyright cent copyright c C
keycode  57 = n N n N U014b N n N n N
```

(3) activate this keyboard redefinition: `xmodmap myfon.xmap`

(4) press (altgr+e) and pray...

Answer (score 2):

[Ctrl]+[Shift]+[U] unlocks Unicode input mode; you can then type the four-hex-digit character code, then [Space], and the character will be inserted inline.

Not an ideal solution for fast typing, though; if speed is a factor, then custom ComposeKey mappings will be slightly faster, and easier to remember.